# How to use multiple forks in one program

Tags: c, process, fork

I'm having trouble ironing out forks apparently. I have code where early within I use the following technique with no problem but later on it causes horrific recursion bugs, so clearly something about my understanding of forks is way off. Regardless of the order I put these in, only the first will execute, with the second apparently doing nothing. If anyone could explain why, or even just point me to an example of how to use multiple forks like this, I would greatly appreciate it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){ 
    int DD, EE;
    char *arg[0];

    
    
    
    EE=fork();
    if (EE==0) 
        execv("EE",arg);

    DD=fork();
    if (DD==0) 
        execv("DD",arg);
    
    exit(0);
}
```

edit: I stepped through with GDB and set the follow mode to child right before the line `DD=fork();`, and DD was the correct value in the child process(0), but nothing happened when I stepped over the execv line. Very confusing

Comment: It seems to me that the argument passed to `execv()` is an uninitialized array. I would think that, as a minimum, `arg` needs to contain at least two entries, the first which conventionally will match the executable filename, and the second a `NULL`.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Execv replaces the image of current process with the parameter you passed. What does `./EE` do?

Comment: @TonyTannous both files print things to cmd, although DD executes a linux command to do so if thats relevant (ps -u [my username])

Comment: `char *arg[0];` is a definition of array of size zero. This is not a legal C

Comment: @KevinBoone the syntax is execv(char * programName, char * arguments[]. I will try adding a NULL but I will be quite pleasantly surprised if that's the issue

Comment: @KevinBoone I am very pleasantly suprised! Adding the NULL to the arg array here worked(after making it larger of course), and I believe it was not just the latter as naturally my array was bigger than 0 in the actual program. Thanks so much!

Comment: Without the terminating NULL, the `execv` implementation has no way to know when it's reached the end of the argument list. C arrays don't carry size information with them, like arrays do in many programming languages, so you have to help the function out by indicating the end of the array. I guess an alternative would have been for `execv` to take a "length" argument, but that isn't how it was done, for better or worse.

Comment: @KevinBoone That makes total sense. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C does not support zero-length arrays, so if this ...

```
    char *arg[0];
```

... compiles, then it is only because you are exercising a language extension provided by your particular C implementation.  Which you have no use for here, anyway, because the the second argument to `execv()` must point to the first element of a null-terminated array of arguments, containing at least one argument (which, by convention, is the name of the program).  `arg` needs at least two elements to accommodate that plus the null pointer terminator.

> nothing happened when I stepped over the execv line

No, undefined behavior happened.  I speculate that the `execv()` failed, possibly because of the bad argument list, which you would have trouble noticing because you do not check the return value.  Presumably, in the event that the exec fails you want to abort by `_Exit()`ing the (child) process with a non-zero exit status.  That would be the usual course of action, anyway.